# Solving this second order differential equation (Damping mechanism)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to self-teach myself differential equations, but I'm having trouble with second order equations! How can I solve this one?

$\frac{3}{32}y''+12y=0$, $y(0)=\frac{-1}{12}$, $y'(0)=2$

Thanks! I'd appreciate if you show step by step so that I can understand it for the rest of the problems.

Consider this to be a damping mechanism now... What would be the bounds on the damping force coefficient k so that oscillatory motion would remain intact?

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the original poster no longer needs the answer and there are already similar questions.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Wait, nevermind. I can't figure out the IVP part

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181331/general-solution-of-second-order-linear-ode?rq=1) might also provide an answer.

Comment: I originally voted to close this because of @JoonasIlmavirta's comment, but the OP has since signaled he still wanted help.  So, I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will map out the steps, but please fill in the details.

Using [*Undetermined Coefficients*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx), we have:

$$\dfrac {3}{32} m^2 + 12 = 0 \implies m_{1,2} = \pm ~8i \sqrt{2}$$

This means our solution is:

$$y(t) = c_1 \cos (8 \sqrt{2} t) + c_2 \sin(8 \sqrt{2} t)$$

Now, find $y'(t)$ and substitute $y'(0)$ and $y(0)$ to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

You should get (hover over area to see spoiler):

> $$y(t) = -\dfrac{1}{12} \cos(8 \sqrt{2} t) + \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \sin(8 \sqrt{2} t)$$

Comment: how did you do that "hover over area"? What's the format??

Comment: What about bounds on the damping force coefficient if oscillatory motion is to be conserved

Comment: A mass weighing 3 lbs stretches a spring 3 inch. skipping the initial conditions part.... Find the position of mass at any time. IF a damping force was introduced, what bounds on the damping constant would be needed so that its oscillatory motion conserved.

Comment: Okay, also, how do i get te answer in form y(t) = Rcos(wt-phi) ?

Comment: huh i dont know how i could do that

Comment: @EricJohnson, you can get that hovering feature by beginning a paragraph with `>!`.